# How Internet Explorer core reacts to uninstallation?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-update, uninstall

Let's say I update my IE8 to IE9 through Windows Update.

Then, I remove IE9 from my computer using the "Turn Windows feature on or off" panel.

The IE application will be gone, but **will my IE core still be IE9 or will it have rolled back to IE8?**

I'm asking this because, while want the IE application to be cleared off my computer, I'd still like to get the security improvements present in the IE9 core.

Answer (score 4):

The upgrade process from 8 -> 9 overwrites the IE core.  The IE core **should** then be the IE9 core.

Comment: @asmo, rewrote answer.

Answer (score 0):

What @TheEvilPhoenix said.

If you truly want to roll back to IE 8, it should be done from the regular Add/Remove Programs (or Programs & Features, or whatever they've decided to call it in your version/edition) dialog - not the Windows Features part.  You may need to check "show updates" to do this.

Still, you're definitely going to lose out on whatever security enhancements are unique to IE 9.  Microsoft still supports and provides security fixes for 8, but any features (security or otherwise) that are 9-only will be gone.

Comment: I don't want to rollback the IE version, I want to remove the IE application, while retaining the latest version of the core for security.